# Getting Injectee from Jersey vs HK2

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

**Short story**: I want to get the `Injectee` from within a `Supplier` that is bound using Jersey's `AbstractBinder.bindFactory(Class)` method.

Basically to work around [JERSEY-3675](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3675)

---

**Long story**: I was using the `org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory` method to create an instance of my `RequestScoped` Object and life was good.

I moved my registration into a Feature and then life was not good because of JERSEY-3675.

Long story short, `org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder` do not work inside Features.  No problem, I thought, I will use `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder`.

Slight problem I encountered: Jersey's `AbstractBinder.bindFactory()` method takes in `Supplier` not `Factory`.  No problem, I thought, I will use `Supplier` (I like it better, anyway).

Bigger problem I encountered: I had been using `org.glassfish.hk2.api.Injectee` to get the `InstantiationData` about who was calling the injection.  This does not get injected if I do not use HK2's `Factory`.  The javadoc even says the method is 'indeterminate' if not called from `Factory.provide()`.

Even though there is a Jersey `Injectee` (`org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injectee`), this seems to only be available when using Jersey's `InjectionResolver`.  I do not want to use `InjectionResolver` because

1. HK2's `InjectionResolver` must be `Singleton` but I want to have `RequestScoped` stuff in my injected object.

   - On second read, though, Jersey's `InjectionResolver` does not say anything about needing to be `Singleton`.  Can anyone confirm?
2. I do not want to create my own annotation for this (I have created my own annotations and `InjectionResolvers` for other cases)
3. I do not feel confident overriding `@Inject` with an `InjectionResolver`.  Not sure what that means or how I would be able to register multiple of those and have them work together (one for each Feature)

In meantime, I am using the workaround mentioned in the bug.

I am new to DI scene, so if something (or all of it) does not make sense, please let me know.

Comment: Seems like maybe the workaround is your best bet at this point.

Comment: Yes, since Jersey went with a more pluggable approach many issues like this come up.  I'm not at all sure how to solve it, the InstantiationData is a feature very specific to hk2

Comment: The InjectionResolver implementation must be in Singleton scope, but it is used to resolve injection points from any scope